# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath problem

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is populated by the method cellForRowAtIndexPath.  There are some rows that I don't want added to the table, so I was returning nil.  According to the documentation that should be legit.  However, I get a crash when I return nil, to the affect that "UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

How can I ignore a row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply return nil. The documentation about the return value reads:

> **Return Value**
>   An object inheriting from
>   UITableViewCell that the table view
>   can use for the specified row. An
>   assertion is raised if you return nil.

In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you should write your logic that will determine the cell to display at the index path specified by the table view. This is not necessarily the same index as the index of an object in an array for example.
This together with the numberOfSectionsInTableView: and tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: methods should give you what you need.

Comment: Well, I was looking at the following documentation:

cellForRowAtIndexPath:
Returns the table cell at the specified index path.

- (UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
Parameters
indexPath
The index path locating the row in the receiver.
Return Value
An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Comment: You are actually looking at the method of the tableview itself. Not of the data source. You can use this method on the tableview when you want the cell used for a specified index path (for altering that one for example). What you want to do is providing the tableview with the cells he needs to display. You should be looking at the method in the [data source documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) since that's the one you're implementing.